# MassTransit: Publish message with specified queue name

Tags: masstransit

Is there any way to publish message with specified queue name in IPublishEndpoint without configure the queue name in startup class?

e.g.: I have this call and i want to pass the queue name inside it

```
await _publishEndpoint.Publish<SendMassege>(new { Body = message.Body });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t publish to queues, you send to queues.

You can get a send endpoint from the `ConsumeContext` or `IBus` by calling `GetSendEndpoint` with a URI specifying the queue name, such as `queue:name`.

Comment: now it work fine but is there a way I can consume that queue in runtime or consume manually meaning i want to send that queue to consume it ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but connecting consumers is covered in the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/consumers.html#consumer)

Comment: I mean I would send a request with a queue name that I created before and I want to consume it without configure that consumer for that queue. is it possible?

Comment: Still not sure, so I'm guessing it isn't something supported that way. MassTransit uses broker-push to receive endpoint and does not support "getting" a message from the broker.

Comment: I got it, Thank you for your support and I appreciate that!